# Why is Warden/Devise appending resource name upon sign_in authentication failure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, warden

I've been googling around for this like crazy and no luck so far.

So far sign_in and sign_out work fine. They redirect to the right action. My problem is when sign_in fails. I get sent to what looks like a blank html page displaying "Invalid login or password." rendered by the **create** action or text rendered by the **create** action . AFAIK **create** should only redirect or render upon failure. I have a custom controller and the only reason I have the devise code listed here is to see where the behavior is occurring.  I really only need to inherit the behavior at this point because I'm not trying to redirect to a custom path after authentication.

the log reads as follows:

```
Started POST "/login.user" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-14 15:50:02 -0700
Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as 
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",   "authenticity_token"=>"Pf2+YBqmb5+231nbuD/MeDlz6H7/qOjV4N50WnlJ0rc=", "user"=>{"login"=>"qwdwqqd", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "x"=>"40", "y"=>"8"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 32ms
```

Here is my controller:

```
Users::SessionsController < ::Devise::SessionsController

def create
  resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
  set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end
```

My routes ar as follows:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => "users/sessions", :registrations => "users/registrations"}, :path => '', :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout' }
.
.
root :to => 'root#index'
```

I determined it is not getting past the

```
resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
```

line upon authentication failure

The resource name is somehow being appended to the login path upon failure by warden it seems.
e.g. /login.user instead of just /login

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Rails 3.2, Devise 2.0.4, rack (1.4.1), ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Have you tried it in production? Could it be related to [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1546)?

Comment: no, i haven't get it past development yet. It may help, I'm in the midst of converting a rails 2 app to rails 3. I'm using database_authenticatable.

Comment: Can I ask why you are overriding the sessions controller?

Comment: only because I wanted to namespace in under User(s) and have some more control oer the views. I'm perfectly OK with calling super for the authentication portion. I actually prefer it. I copypasta'd the code from github only to pin down the culpable line.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else was still wondering. I removed the resource argument in the create_user_session form. In other words I went from this:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_session_path(resource)) do |f| %>
```

to this:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_session_path) do |f| %>
```

that did the trick. I feel pretty dumb for not looking here earlier.